# Clustering WSO2 IS as Key Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

1. We have 3 VMs’ for APIM and 3 VM’s for IS. The plan for us is to create 3 IS instances as a key store for the APIM. Can anyone provide input on how we can cluster the 3 IS instances and add them as the key stores for the APIM?
2. Is it possible to setup multiple key store instances of APIM?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the question that you are asking should be more clear. What you are trying to get clarified is that you are going to setup WSO2 IS as Key Manager having 3 IS nodes as Key Manager for WSO2 API Manager.

Yes you can do this. So the recommended way is to cluster the 3 Key Manager instances. Better if you can front it by a load balancer  so that Session affinity is not mandatory. (In a clustered environment, you use session affinity to ensure that requests from the same client alway get routed to the same server). And the 3 API Manager nodes, you can configure them to be used as Publisher, Store and Gateway. 
You haven't specifically mentioned what is the API Manager version that you are using. If it is APIM 2.0.0 or higher, a new component called Traffic Manager added to the deployment. And you can find what is the compatible WSO2 Identity Server version for each WSO2 APIM version by following the API Manager documentation of each version.

Please follow the reference [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/API+Manager+Deployment+Patterns#APIManagerDeploymentPatterns-Distributeddeploymentpatterns) for to get more idea about the deployment patterns of WSO2 API Manager.